# Depending type of var on if loop

Tags: c++

Let's say I want to do this:

```cpp
type variable; 

if(condition1){
 variable=  something of class A
}
else if(condition2){
 variable = something of class B
}

do more with / variable
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: C++ does not work this way, sorry. "variable" must have a specific type. Either use type conversions, or `std::variant`.

Comment: You can also *try* using `std::any` from `<any>` or `boost::any` if you aren't using C++17. Later on you can use `std::any_cast<T1>(variable)`, etc.

Comment: Are class A and B related? Is condition1/condition2 a compile time constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with *pointers*, so long as your `A` and `B` classes share a common base; like this:

```cpp
class Base {
    //...
public:
    virtual ~Base() {} // MUST have VIRTUAL member for dynamic_cast
};

class A : public Base {
    //...
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public Base {
    //...
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};

    // ... 
    bool condition = true;
    Base* variable;
    if (condition)
        variable = new A;
    else
        variable = new B;
    //...
```

Once you have created your class object (and provided that the classes have *at least one* virtual function), then you can, in later code, 'ask' what type of object it *actually* is using the [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) operator:

```cpp
    // ... continuing in the same scope as the previous code...
    if (dynamic_cast<A*>(variable) != nullptr) { // Points to an A object:
        // Do something specific to A
    //  A* ptrA = dynamic_cast<A*>(variable);
    //  ptrA->member = value;
    }
    else if (dynamic_cast<B*>(variable) != nullptr) { // Points to a B object:
        // Do something specific to B
    }
    else { // Not an A or a B...
        // (error handling?)
    }
    //...
    // And, of course, don't forget to free the object when finished:
    delete variable;
```

Comment: You need `delete`, whereas you might use smart pointer, and 'depending how you delete), you need a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 Of course! The code I gave was intended as a minimal example, in the same 'spirit' as the OP's question. But I have added a note as an edit.

Comment: OP has to write pseudo-code, as OP doesn't know how to do with regular code. Answer has to be complete and not creating other issues. At least, with the note, it is clearer that it is a incomplete answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole this is exactly what i'm trying to do. The two classes A and B both have members "string", but Base-class does not.
In the if statment i'm trying to do a dynamic cast, so can't just do new dynamic_cast ...

Comment: @Jarod42 Actually, your comment and the OP's made me realise that my answer was actually inadequate, as it stood. I have added more detail, having considered your points. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @user3489433 Have a look at my latest edit - does this help more?

Comment: Comment are also to improve question/answer, so feel free to consider my points :-)

Answer (score 1):

> How can i achieve this?

You cannot achieve this in C++ nor in any other statically typed language. The type of a variable cannot change.

A few alternatives:

Declare a different variable, within different scopes:

```
if(condition1){
 A variable=  something of class A
 do more with / variable
}
else if(condition2){
 B variable = something of class B
 do more with / variable
}
```

Or use a form of runtime polymorphism such as a tagged union (`std::variant`) or inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

pull "do more with" into functions, perhaps differing for `A` and `B`.

```
void do_more_with(A variable)
{
    // A specific things
}

void do_more_with(B variable)
{
    // B specific things
}
```

or

```
template <typename T>
void do_more_with(T variable)
{
    // things both A and B do
}
```

or

```
void do_more_with(Common variable)
{
    // A and B both convert to Common
}
```

Those are all used the same way

```
int main()
{
    if(condition1){
        do_more_with(something_A);
    }
    else if(condition2){
        do_more_with(something_B);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic way to do it, that doesn't require the two classes to have a common base.

Put the code that uses the variable into a generic lambda, then use tag dispatch to call said lambda.

```
template <typename T> struct tag {using type = T;};

// ...

auto lambda = [](auto tag)
{
    using type = typename decltype(tag)::type;
    // Here `type` is either class A or class B.
    type variable = something;
    // Use `variable` here.
};

if (condition1)
    lambda(tag<A>{});
else if (condition2)
    lambda(tag<B>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Simpler would be to create sub function, possibly template.

  ```
  if (condition1) {
    do_job(A{});
  }
  else if (condition2){
    do_job(B{});
  }
  ```
- Other alternative need to find a common type for `A` and `B`:

  - if they have common base class, you might do something like:

    ```
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base;
    if (condition1) {
      base = std::make_unique<A>();
    }
    else if (condition2){
      base = std::make_unique<B>();
    }
    if (base) { // "limited" to base interface (including dispatch).
        // free function
        do_job(*base);
        // or member (virtual) function
        base->do_job();
        // or visitor pattern
        base->visit(do_job_visitor{});
    }
    ```
  - If types are unrelated, `std::variant` is a good option:

    ```
    std::optional<std::variant<A, B>> value;
    if (condition1) {
      value = A{};
    }
    else if (condition2){
      value = B{};
    }
    if (value) {
        std::visit([](auto a_or_b){ do_job(a_or_b); }, *value);
    }
    ```

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions are only known at run-time, then this is not possible. In a statically typed language, a variable must have exactly one type, and it cannot change. To do this, you would need a level of indirection, e.g. using algebraic types like `std::variant`, or run-time polymorphism, or you'd need to abstract some of the code away into a template.

If you *do* know the conditions at compile-time (or they can be calculated at compile-time), then you can do this quite easily.

```
auto var = [] {
  if constexpr (condition1)
    return A{};
  else if constexpr (condition2)
    return B{};
}();
```

Now `var` will have the type `A` or `B` according to the conditions.